# getting problem while executing ./bootstrap

Tags: bash

**bootstrap file content :**

```
!/usr/bin/env bash 
# The contents of this file are subject to the MonetDB Public License
# Version 1.1 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in # compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at 
# http://monetdb.cwi.nl/Legal/MonetDBLicense-1.1.html
# # Software distributed under the License is distributed on an     "AS IS"
# basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
# License for the specific language governing rights and limitations # under the License.
# # The Original Code is the MonetDB Database System.
# # The Initial Developer of the Original Code is CWI.
# Portions created by CWI are Copyright (C) 1997-July 2008 CWI. 
# Copyright August 2008-2011 MonetDB B.V. # All Rights Reserved. 
# NOTE: if you happen to have bootstrap failures due to missing M4
# macros, export M4DIRS as a space separated list of directories where 
# aclocal should look in your environment.


PYTHONPATH=${PWD:-$(pwd)}/buildtools/autogen${PYTHONPATH:+:$PYTHONPATH}
export PYTHONPATH

# cope with systems where libtool is not GNU libtool, e.g. Darwin
type -P glibtoolize > /dev/null \
    && libtoolize=glibtoolize \
    || libtoolize=libtoolize

_m4_extra_dirs=
if [[ -n ${M4DIRS} ]] ; then
    for d in ${M4DIRS} ; do
        case ${d} in
            "-I")  d=          ;;
            "-I"*) d=${d#-I}   ;;
        esac
        [[ -n ${d} ]] && _m4_extra_dirs="${_m4_extra_dirs} -I ${d}"
    done
fi

python buildtools/autogen/autogen.py &&
(
# replace the line starting with AC_CONFIG_FILES in configure.ag with
# the command to substitute the configure results into the .in files,
# making sure executable files remain executable.
sed -n '/^AC_CONFIG_FILES/s/.*/AC_CONFIG_FILES([/;1,/^AC_CONFIG_FILES/p' configure.ag
while read f; do [ -x $f.in ] || echo $f; done < acout.in
echo '])'
while read f; do [ -x $f.in ] && echo "AC_CONFIG_FILES([$f], [chmod +x $f])"; done < acout.in
sed '1,/^AC_CONFIG_FILES/d' configure.ag
) > configure.ac &&
$libtoolize -c -f  &&
aclocal -I . -I buildtools/conf ${_m4_extra_dirs} &&
autoheader  &&
automake --add-missing --copy --foreign  &&
autoconf
```

when i run command ./bootstrap , i get this error

```
python : can't open file 'buildtools/autogen.py': [error 2] No such file or directory
```

what is the requirement to execute this command successfully.

Comment: Where do this scripts located? It is said `No such file or directory`, can you try to execute this command `locate autogen.py`, and put here output

Comment: thanks i corrected that one but now i m getting problem for libtool

Comment: libtool command not found ...and i tried to solve this pbm with

Comment: sudo apt-get install libtool having error E: Package 'libtool' has no installation candidate.

Comment: Try run `sudo apt-get update` before install

Comment: when we can say updated successfully! Bcoz when i update always comes failed to update few packages and used old one.